# Mapping Entity using sql query via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I would like to map Entity into another Entity (1:1) and specifying condition in sql expression using Hibernate.

I have ERA scheme with tables Position and Subject. Subject has relationship 1:N to positions.
Each Position has date of creation. I would like to *map last created position* (one from N with same subject_id) as entity *into entity Subject* via hibernate.

I tried @Formula but wasn't successful.

```
@Entity
public class Position {
  ..
}

@Entity
public class Subject {
  ..

  @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)        
  @Formula("select p.* from position p inner join (select subject_id, max(position_date) maxdate from position where subject_id = 3743073 group by subject_id ) pmaxgrouped on p.subject_id = pmaxgrouped.subject_id and p.position_date = pmaxgrouped.maxdate")
  private Position lastPosition;
}
```

Hibernate mismatches result sql query.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT giposobj0_.POSOBJ_ID    AS POSOBJ1_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_AGENDA_ID      AS SYS2_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_INS_DATE       AS SYS3_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_LOGIN_ID_INS   AS SYS4_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_LOGIN_ID_UPD   AS SYS5_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_UPD_DATE       AS SYS6_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_LOGIN_ID_OWNER AS SYS7_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_ORGUNIT_ID     AS SYS8_1688_,
    giposobj0_.SYS_PUBKIND_LEVEL  AS SYS9_1688_,
    giposobj0_.POSOBJ_CODE        AS POSOBJ10_1688_,
    giposobj0_.POSOBJ_IMEI        AS POSOBJ11_1688_,
    giposobj0_.POSOBJ_LASTSTATUS  AS POSOBJ12_1688_,
    giposobj0_.POSOBJ_MODEL       AS POSOBJ13_1688_,
    giposobj0_.POSOBJ_NOTIF       AS POSOBJ14_1688_,
  SELECT p.*
  FROM position p
  INNER JOIN
    (SELECT giposobj0_.posobj_id,
      MAX(giposobj0_.position_date) giposobj0_.maxdate
    FROM position
    WHERE giposobj0_.posobj_id = 3743073
    GROUP BY giposobj0_.posobj_id
    ) giposobj0_.pmaxgrouped
  ON p.posobj_id      = pmaxgrouped.posobj_id
  AND p.position_date = pmaxgrouped.maxdate AS formula11_
  FROM eira_gi.VS_POSOBJ giposobj0_
  WHERE giposobj0_.POSOBJ_IMEI=111111111111111
  );
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this. What if there isn't any positions, and your subselect returns 0 results?
If you are using cashes after modifying positions "lastPosition" won't be updated.

Comment: If there wouldn't be any positions, hibernate could have returned null for the field "lastPosition".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option1: You create a ordered list with [@OrderBy](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/OrderBy.html). Subsequently, you can return the last object from that collection. Here is a very nice [tutorial](http://www.stevideter.com/2008/10/20/annotation-mapping-for-ordered-lists-in-hibernate/).

Option2: Save the correlated "lastPosition" every time you saveOrUpdate a Subject.